# eclipse jave project with two source directories - how to set the visibility of the source folders

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java project in eclipse - within the project I want to configure two source directories:

1. src-api
2. src-core

This is simple.

The problem is that I want src-core to be able to access src-api, but I don't want src-api to access src-core, I want eclipse to not let me compile and be able to find classes configured in src-core only from the src-api.

Is it possible to do so?

I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible.

Just create two different project `api` & `core`. Then make `core` project dependent to `api` project.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two different projects, one for src-api and one for .
The src-core should have src-api as a dependency, but not vice versa.